# Is it possible to safely get a SecureString value from VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, securestring

I've always felt like SecureString was a little odd, but assumed most of my issues with it were due to security problems I don't understand.  Today I decided to sit down and teach myself about it, but I've hit what seems like a fatal snag.

The scenario I envision is "user enters password into text box, that password is hashed and compared to a stored hash".  At first I was worried that the text box contained the string, but then I realized you could roll a custom text box that uses SecureString as its store.  Cool.  It's the "that password is hashed and compared..." part that is giving me trouble.

My first hack at the problem in VB .NET was naive and wrong:

```
Dim passwordHandle As IntPtr
Dim insecurePassword As String = Nothing
Try
    passwordHandle = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(_password)
    insecurePassword = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(passwordHandle)
Catch ex As Exception

Finally
    If passwordHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(passwordHandle)
    End If
End Try

If insecurePassword <> Nothing Then
    ' Do hash and comparison
End If
```

This just stuffs the password into a regular string and defeats the purpose of using SecureString in the first place.  So I kept searching and found [a blog post](http://dotnet.org.za/markn/archive/2008/10/04/handling-passwords.aspx) that solves the problem nicely in C#: the string is made into a BSTR, copied into a pinned string, then both the BSTR and pinned string are zeroed after use.  This seems like a much better idea because it minimizes the amount of time that the insecure string is in memory.  However, it doesn't look like there's a way to pull this off in VB .NET.  C# is using its unsafe code feature to do pointer manipulations, but VB .NET cannot do this.  I had a look at Marhsall.Copy(), but it looks like it's oriented towards arrays.  I thought about trying to cast the IntPtr variables for the object and BSTR to Strings, but that still left me using a method like String.Replace(), which will create a new string.

Is it not possible to do this from VB .NET at all, or is there something I'm missing?

*edit*
I'm accepting AMissico's answer with only slight reservations. The Marshal.ReadByte() method will copy a byte from unmanaged memory and create a byte in unmanaged memory. This produces the small chance that an attacker could find the individual characters of the password. I think that's far less than the odds of finding an entire string, but the C# in the (apparently defunct) article I referenced was able to use unsafe code to avoid this neatly. The thought process was it used GCHandle to pin a string in memory, then used unsafe code to get around the immutability of .NET strings. Clever trick that seems impossible in VB .NET. I'll try to come back with the C# code itself.

Comment: Is there a reason that it must be written in VB.NET?  If C# has better support for what is required, then I would write the solution in C#.

Comment: The reason is because it's something I want to show to people most comfortable with VB .NET.  Still, it's not an answer to say this. Suppose I had a 100,000 line sprawling enterprise app written in VB .NET; would it really make sense to roll a class library for 1 C# file to support this?

This is a class that's part of the .NET Framework and important for a relatively common use case; if one of the primary .NET languages can't use it it's a pretty big deal.

Comment: *shrugs* - From the article you linked to, it seems that the problem is that SecureString is relatively new, and once the rest of the framework is updated, it can be used without ever casting it to a String, and everything will be fine (in VB and C#).  Personally, if something has to be done, I get it done, even if that means using a tiny class library in a different language.

Comment: Have you continued with this? I am interested in your final VB.NET code. After reviewing the article, you will have to use addressof/methods instead of the lamba expressions, but that shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to "Marshaling SecureString Passwords to String - Mark Nicholson
" at http://dotnet.org.za/markn/archive/2008/10/04/handling-passwords.aspx finally displayed.

So your statement, "C# is using its unsafe code feature to do pointer manipulations," seems to be addressed with "HOW TO: Wrap a UCOMIStream in a Stream Class in Visual Basic .NET" at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321695. (I searched on "AddrOfPinnedObject".)

<strike>I did not read your whole question (link to post always timed out), but</strike> are these classes and testing code helpful? The password never lives as a System.String; therefore, you need a SecureStringTextBox implementation as noted in your question.

I dislike adding all this code. Let me know what code is helpful, and I will edit the answer to keep only the helpful stuff.

```
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

''' <summary>
''' Helper class to programmatically impersonate a user, load and unload a user's profile, and perform other maintenance-related tasks for impersonating a user.
''' </summary>
Public Class ImpersonationHelper
    Implements IDisposable

#Region " IDisposable Implementaton "

    Private _disposed As Boolean

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        Dispose(False)
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Implementation of the <b>IDisposable</b> interface.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>This method calls <see>Undo</see> if impersonation is still being performed. This method calls the common language runtime version of the Dispose method.</remarks>
    Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        System.GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Implementation of the <b>IDisposable</b> interface.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="disposing">If <b>true</b>, the object to be disposed is finalized and collected by the garbage collector; otherwise, <b>false</b>.</param>
    ''' <remarks>This method calls Undo if impersonation is still being performed. This method calls the common language runtime version of the Dispose method.</remarks>
    Protected Overloads Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not _disposed Then
            If disposing Then
                If Not IsNothing(_impersonationContext) Then
                    _impersonationContext.Undo()
                    _impersonationContext.Dispose()
                End If
            End If
            _impersonationContext = Nothing
        End If
        _disposed = True
    End Sub

#End Region

    '2009.02.12 AMJ
    '   Modified From:
    '       How to implement impersonation in an ASP.NET application (KB306158)
    '       http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158
    '   Implemented IDisposable based on ImpersonationHelper class of
    '       Namespace: Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Addins.ComputeCluster.Security
    '       Assembly: Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Addins.ComputeCluster (in microsoft.office.excel.server.addins.computecluster.dll)

    Const LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Integer = 2
    Const LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH As Integer = 4
    Const LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE As Integer = 5

    Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT As Integer = 0
    Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 As Integer = 1

    Private Enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
        SecurityAnonymous = 0
        SecurityIdentification = 1
        SecurityImpersonation = 2
        SecurityDelegation = 3
    End Enum

    Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
        ByVal username As String, _
        ByVal domain As String, _
        ByVal password As IntPtr, _
        ByVal logonType As Integer, _
        ByVal logonProvider As Integer, _
        ByRef token As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Private Declare Auto Function DuplicateToken Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
        ByVal ExistingTokenHandle As IntPtr, _
        ByVal ImpersonationLevel As SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, _
        ByRef DuplicateTokenHandle As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private Declare Auto Function RevertToSelf Lib "advapi32.dll" () As Long
    Private Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Long

    Dim _impersonationContext As WindowsImpersonationContext
    Dim _domain As String
    Dim _login As String
    Dim _password As SecureString

#Region " Standard Constructor & Properties "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the ImpersonationHelper class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="domain">The domain or computer name of the user to impersonate.</param>
    ''' <param name="userName">The user name of the user to impersonate.</param>
    ''' <param name="password">The secure string password of UserName. For more information about secure strings, see the <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">SecureString</see> class.</param>
    <DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Public Sub New(ByVal domain As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As SecureString)
        Me.Domain = domain
        Me.Login = userName
        Me.Password = password
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Do not allow a new instance of the ImpersonationHelper class without credentials.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub New()

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the domain of the user to impersonate.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The domain of the user.</value>
    <DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Public Property Domain() As String
        Get
            Return _domain
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _domain = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the user name of the user to impersonate.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The user name.</value>
    <DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Public Property Login() As String
        Get
            Return _login
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _login = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets the encrypted password of the user to impersonate. 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The encrypted password.</value>
    <DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Public WriteOnly Property Password() As SecureString
        Set(ByVal value As SecureString)
            _password = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Performs the impersonation of the user based on the parameters provided in the constructor. 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' <para>If logon fails using the supplied credentials, an exception is thrown. The exception is thrown because this method is unable to duplicate the logged-on user's token for purposes of impersonation or is unable to create a Windows identity from the user's impersonated token.</para>
    ''' <para>For details about the direct cause of the impersonation failure, you can inspect the inner exception.</para>
    ''' </remarks>
    <PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
    Public Sub ImpersonateUser()

        Dim fResult As Boolean = False  'assume impersonation failed

        Dim hPassword As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim hToken As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim hTokenDuplicate As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim oException As ImpersonationException = Nothing

        If RevertToSelf <> 0 Then

            hPassword = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(_password)

            If LogonUser(Me.Login, Me.Domain, hPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, hToken) Then
                If DuplicateToken(hToken, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, hTokenDuplicate) <> 0 Then
                    _impersonationContext = New WindowsIdentity(hTokenDuplicate).Impersonate()
                    If Not _impersonationContext Is Nothing Then
                        fResult = True
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                oException = New ImpersonationException(Me.Login, Me.Domain)
            End If

            If hPassword.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) = False Then
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(hPassword)
            End If

        End If

        If Not hTokenDuplicate.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
            CloseHandle(hTokenDuplicate)
        End If

        If Not hToken.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
            CloseHandle(hToken)
        End If

        If Not (oException Is Nothing) Then
            Throw oException
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Undoes the impersonation of the user, if it is impersonated.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>Use this method to free the objects associated with impersonation.</remarks>
    <PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
    <DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Public Sub Undo()
        _impersonationContext.Undo()
        _impersonationContext = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function InvokeAsUser(ByVal userName As String, ByVal domain As String, ByVal password As SecureString, ByVal methodToCall As [Delegate], ByVal ParamArray parameters() As Object) As Object
        Dim oResult As Object = Nothing

        Using oImpersonation As New ImpersonationHelper(domain, userName, password)

            oImpersonation.ImpersonateUser()

            oResult = methodToCall.DynamicInvoke(parameters)

        End Using

        Return oResult
    End Function

End Class

Public Class ImpersonationException
    Inherits System.Exception

    Public ReadOnly Login As String
    Public ReadOnly Domain As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal userName As String, ByVal domain As String)
        MyBase.New(String.Format("Impersonation failure: {1}\{0}", userName, domain), New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Imports Missico.Personal

Imports System.Security

Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()> _
Public Class ImpersonationHelperTest

    Private testContextInstance As TestContext

    Public Property TestContext() As TestContext
        Get
            Return testContextInstance
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As TestContext)
            testContextInstance = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <TestMethod()> _
    Public Sub ImpersonationHelperTest()

        'testing only, never initialize the characters of the password in this fashion
        'replace with valid password

        Dim oPassword As New System.Security.SecureString

        oPassword.AppendChar("o"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("o"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("p"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("s"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("!"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar(" "c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("n"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("o"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar(" "c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("p"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("a"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("s"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("s"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("w"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("o"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("r"c)
        oPassword.AppendChar("d"c)

        Using oImpersonation As New ImpersonationHelper("ANTHONY", "amissico", oPassword)

            oImpersonation.ImpersonateUser()

            '...

        End Using

        Try

            Using oImpersonation As New ImpersonationHelper("INVALID", "amissico", oPassword)

                oImpersonation.ImpersonateUser()

                '...

            End Using

        Catch ex As ImpersonationException
            'expected
            '   due to invalid domain
        End Try


        Try

            Using oImpersonation As New ImpersonationHelper("ANTHONY", "INVALID", oPassword)

                oImpersonation.ImpersonateUser()

                '...

            End Using

        Catch ex As ImpersonationException
            'expected
            '   due to invalid user

        End Try

        Try

            oPassword.AppendChar(" "c) 'invalidate password

            Using oImpersonation As New ImpersonationHelper("ANTHONY", "amissico", oPassword)

                oImpersonation.ImpersonateUser()

                '...

            End Using

        Catch ex As ImpersonationException
            'expected
            '   due to invalid password

        End Try


    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module SecureStringExtensions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">System.Security.SecureString</see> instances are considered equal.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="valueA">The first <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">System.Security.SecureString</see> to compare.</param>
    ''' <param name="valueB">The second <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">System.Security.SecureString</see> to compare.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if valueA is equal to valueB; otherwise, False.</returns>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Equals(ByVal valueA As SecureString, ByVal valueB As SecureString) As Boolean
        Return IsEqual(valueA, valueB)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether the specified <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">System.Security.SecureString</see> instances are considered equal.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="valueA">The first <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">System.Security.SecureString</see> to compare.</param>
    ''' <param name="valueB">The second <see cref="System.Security.SecureString">System.Security.SecureString</see> to compare.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if valueA is equal to valueB; otherwise, False.</returns>
    ''' <remarks>Comparison loop based on Microsoft souce code for String.EqualsHelper method.</remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function IsEqual(ByVal valueA As SecureString, ByVal valueB As SecureString) As Boolean
        Dim fResult As Boolean = False  'assume failure

        'short-circuit if lengths are not the same

        If valueA.Length <> valueB.Length Then
            'cannot be the same value
            Return False
        End If

        Using oCopyA As SecureString = valueA.Copy, oCopyB As SecureString = valueB.Copy

            Dim iLength As Integer = oCopyA.Length

            Dim oPtrA As IntPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(oCopyA)
            Dim oPtrB As IntPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(oCopyB)

            Try

                Do While (iLength > 0)

                    If Marshal.ReadByte(oPtrA, iLength) <> Marshal.ReadByte(oPtrB, iLength) Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                    iLength -= 1

                Loop

                fResult = (iLength <= 0)

            Finally
                Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(oPtrA)
                Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(oPtrA)

            End Try

        End Using

        Return fResult
    End Function

End Module
```

---

```
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Diagnostics

Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Imports Missico.Security.SecureStringExtensions

<TestClass()> _
Public Class SecureStringExtensionsFixture

#Region " TestContext "

    Private testContextInstance As TestContext

    Public Property TestContext() As TestContext
        Get
            Return testContextInstance
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As TestContext)
            testContextInstance = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

    <TestMethod()> _
    Public Sub EqualsTest()

        Dim oValueA As New SecureString
        Dim oValueB As New SecureString

        oValueA.AppendChar("p"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("a"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("s"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("s"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("w"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("o"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("r"c)
        oValueA.AppendChar("d"c)

        oValueB.AppendChar("p"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("a"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("s"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("s"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("w"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("o"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("r"c)
        oValueB.AppendChar("d"c)


        'The Object.Equal method does not work because you cannot compare to secure strings.

        If oValueA.Equals(oValueB) Then
            'expected, but does not work
            'you cannot compare two secure strings
        Else
            'always fails
        End If


        'Using the fully-qualified path to the Equal extension method.

        If Missico.Security.SecureStringExtensions.Equals(oValueA, oValueB) Then
            'expected
        Else
            Assert.Fail("SecureString values are not equal, which is not expected.")
        End If


        'Using the IsEqual extension method that does not conflict with the Object.Equal method.

        If oValueA.IsEqual(oValueB) Then
            'expected
        Else
            Assert.Fail("SecureString values are not equal, which is not expected.")
        End If


        'change the second value

        oValueB.AppendChar(" "c)

        If oValueA.IsEqual(oValueB) Then
            Assert.Fail("SecureString values are equal, which is not expected.")
        Else
            'expected
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't think so, but you didn't list the code for a lot of your methods.  Still, the password is being copied into the _password string, which is subject to GC and thus will stay around longer than needed.  The code I linked to pins a managed string in memory so it won't be moved, copies the password into it, and when it's done it zeroes the string's memory.  The string still sticks around until the GC collects it, but now it's zeroed.  Your code doesn't do that, it only zeroes the unmanaged string.

Comment: The link to "Marshaling SecureString Passwords to String - Mark Nicholson" finally displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't come back to this sooner; it's something I forgot about. I can't get the original page to load anymore; a shame because I think it had some additional concerns. As it stands, your code looks the closest to what all of the C# examples I can find would look like in VB .NET. I have one concern I will edit into my question, but I think you deserve the credit until someone can come up with a better solution.

Comment: @OwenP: I saved article due to display problems. You want me to send?

Comment: That sure would be nice; my email is quite guessable and even strongly hinted at if you visit my site at http://owenpellegrin.com

Answer (score 0):

All of the examples I've seen fail to take into account the fact that the logon type is not a one size fits all solution.

For example this will only work if the user you are impersonating has permission to logon to the target system.  Not always the case when accessing a remote SQL Server box.  LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE

NetworkClearText is the only one that works consistently for use with SQL Server connections.
 - No clear text does not mean it is passing credentials in an insecure manner.

When on a workgroup and you need to impersonate a domain user NewCredentials is the one that works.  (not tested with SQL Server connections)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a correction to the code above:

the line

```
   Dim iLength As Integer = oCopyA.Length
```

is icorrect.  As written the Function IsEqual will test for only half+1 of the characters in the strings.

The correct line should be:

```
   Dim iLength As Integer = oCopyA.Length*2-1
```

since BSTR uses 2 bytes per character, and the index starts at zero, as usual.  Length gives the number of characters, not bytes.

Otherwise, it seems to work.

cignaciob

Regards